# Spring Security doesn't save authentication

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, spring-restcontroller

I'm having the following problem:
I want to access the Authentication object inside the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication`

The code I'm using to save the user's authentication is the following;
    `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));`

How I'm using it is as follows;

I send a request by using `localhost:8080/api/login/<username>/<password>`

Afterwards I want to retrieve a list of messages for the logged in user using `localhost:8080/api/messages`

When I print out the Authentication object, it always returns an anonymous user although I'm setting the Authentication object in my login method.

Comment: Are you setting and getting the authentication in the same thread? The SecurityContextHolder "Associates a given SecurityContext with the current execution thread"

Comment: No I'm not, but shouldn't Spring Security save who is logged in? Else I would need to authenticate the user every time someone makes a request.

Comment: Right but Spring Security should do this automatically without you having to manually register an AuthenticationToken. I suggest you check some tutorials for that online.

Comment: I'm using a custom login method using the RestController. What's the native way to do it then?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to authenticate a user manually it looks like the following:

Create token:

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
```

Authenticate:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Comment: I'm using this already, and when I try to retrieve the authentication it returns an anonymoususer (when I'm making another REST call)